# How to add the map objects to the List in java

Tags: java

I have created a `HashMap` and for that I am adding the `username` and `displayname` and now I am passing each userid to another class that returns the the map with a count value. Now In this I need to return both of the map objects.

```
public class ReporteeList {

    public Map<Object, Object> getReportees(String idOfEmp) {
        HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        if (jsonarr_s.size() > 0) {

            // Get data for List array
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject) jsonarr_s.get(i);
                JSONObject jive = (JSONObject) jsonobj_1.get("jive");

                Object names = jsonobj_1.get("displayName");
                Object userid = jive.get("username");
                String UserId = userid.toString();

                map.put(names, userid);
                //return the map with the key value pairs

                map = count.getJiraCount(UserId);


            }

            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

If at all if I need to use `List` then how can that be implemented here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What list? Which objects do you want in a list?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: You're adding objects to the `map` and then just wipe everything out by reassigning it to `count.getJiraCount(UserId)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Stright forward solution

You have to retrieve list of pairs **username/display name** + **count map** as additional data. Then you could retrieve list of `Map`:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getReportees(String idOfEmp) {
    if (jsonarr_s.size() <= 0)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<Map<String, String>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String names = String.valueOf(((JSONObject)jsonarr_s.get(i)).get("displayName"));
        String userid = String.valueOf(((JSONObject)jsonobj_1.get("jive")).get("username"));
        map.put(names, userid);
        map.putAll(count.getJiraCount(userid));

        res.add(map);
    }

    return res;
}
```

#### Better solution

Better solution is to define data class and save all information in it, instead of `Map`.

```
public static final class User {
    private final String userName;
    private final String displayName;
    private final Map<?, ?> jiraCount;  // do not know what data is returned with `count.getJiraCount()`

    public User(String userName, String displayName, Map<?, ?> jiraCount) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.jiraCount = jiraCount;
    }
}

public List<User> getReportees(String idOfEmp) {
    if (jsonarr_s.size() <= 0)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<User> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {
        String userName = (((JSONObject)jsonobj_1.get("jive")).getString("username"));
        String displayName = ((JSONObject)jsonarr_s.get(i)).getString("displayName");
        Map<?, ?> jiraCount = count.getJiraCount(userid);
        res.add(new User(userName, displayName, jiraCount));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood is that you want to return multiple maps in a list (Please correct me if I didn't understand the question correctly):

To create a list: `List<Map<Object, Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Then use `myList.add(map)` to add maps to this list.